# MySQL Inner Join for same field twice as different labels

Tags: mysql

Given:

MariaDB on CentOS 7

Table telephones

- tp_id //primary key
- tp_p_id // foreign key to programs table
- tp_num_type //fax, primary, hunt, cell, alarm
- tp_num // the telephone number

Table programs (our term for different locations) 1:many with Telephones

- p_id //primary key
- p_name // program name

**Question** I'd like to have a query that selects the program data and then tp_num as tp_primary where tp_num_type = 'primary', and then also tp_num as tp_fax where tp_num_type = 'fax'.

What I have...

```
SELECT p_name, tp_num as tp_primary 
FROM programs 
INNER JOIN telephones ON p_id = tp_p_id
WHERE p_id = 1 AND tp_num_type = 'Primary';
```

I just don't have any idea how to do the second inner join from tp_num as tp_fax. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or do I have to do a subquery for this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do another `JOIN` to telephones table to get the fax.

```
SELECT p.p_name, t.tp_num as tp_primary, f.tp_num as tp_fax
FROM programs p
INNER JOIN telephones t ON p.p_id = t.tp_p_id AND t.tp_num_type = 'Primary'
LEFT JOIN telephones f ON p.p_id = f.tp_p_id AND f.tp_num_type = 'Fax'
WHERE p.p_id = 1;
```

Comment: Ahhh- so I have to alias "telephones" as two distinct tables, once as "t", once as "f". That was the logic I couldn't come up with. Thanks!